# Is there a way to add conditions to an if statement in recursion using java?

Tags: java, recursion

as practice, I am trying to develop a program to input scrambled letters and find a valid word from a given dictionary.  I am able to get this to work using just nested for loops, however, the code gets huge and repetitive.  I am looking at rebuilding the loop structure as a recursive method, but I do not know how and if I can add conditions to an if statement through recursion.

```
//Sample example for "pie"
//"word" is a linked list stack
//each node in the list is a "letter"
word.push('i');
word.push('p');
word.push('e');
for(int a=word.length();a>0;a--) {
    for(int b=word.length();b>0;b--){
        if(b!=a)
            for(int c=word.length();c>0;c--){
                if(c!=b&&c!=a) {
                    order = {a,b,c};
                    if(IsWord(word.toString(order))){    
                        System.out.println(word.toString(order));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

What I was thinking of doing was a recursive method that starts by taking in the scrambled word in a stack and making an int[], which is used recursively to add into the if statement.

First layer has if(b!=a)//two letter word

Second layer has if(c!=b&&c!=a)//three letter word

third layer has if(d!=c&&d!=b&&d!=a)//four letter word

etc...

```
public static String descramble(int word) {
    int[] letterPos = new int[word.length()];
    for(int a=wordList[word].length();a>0;a--) {
        letterPos[0] = a;
        return descramble(word, letterPos, 1);
    }
    return null;
}
public static String descramble(int word, int[] letterPos, int pos) {
    if(letterPos.length == pos){//final position, only has one possible letter remaining
        for(int a=wordList[word].length();a>0;a--) {
            letterPos[pos] = a;
            if(letterPos[pos]!=letterPos[pos-1])//this needs to add conditions as the recursion goes deeper
                return word.toString(letterPos);
        }
    }
    for(int a=wordList[word].length();a>0;a--) {
        letterPos[pos] = a;
        if(letterPos[pos]!=letterPos[pos-1])//this needs to add conditions as the recursion goes deeper
            return descramble(word, letterPos, pos+1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT 1:  an example of what I am trying to solve is the word scramble problem found inside of your local newspapers.  The problems are relatively simple where you are given 4-6 characters per word and you are supposed to find a valid word that is spelled by those letters.  The first code example is a hard example for any three letter word, the for loops go through all the possible combinations of the letters while the if statements prevent duplication of letters.  Once all letters are given a position, the string made is then sent to the IsWord() method that runs through a dictionary list of words until it finds a valid word, or fails.  That part I have working with no issue and is given that will return a true/false if there is a match.

Comment: I cannot really follow what you are trying to achieve, can you please add an example to clarify your question?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to sort the letters of your dictionary words in alphabetical order, sort the input word letters in alphabetical order, and do straight comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a slightly different algorithmic approach. By matching a anagram word sorted by character against a hash map of similarly character ordered key to values of dictionary words
For example using a dictionary subset of English words [wordlist.10000.txt](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eecprice/wordlist.10000)
Here *abel*, *labe* and *bela* will all permit **able** to be matched

Note this needs to cope with situations where an anagram could resolve to multiple words for example 'same' and 'seam'

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> anagramToWord = new HashMap<>();
populateAnagramLookup(anagramToWord);

lookupWord(anagramToWord, "abel");
lookupWord(anagramToWord, "labe");
lookupWord(anagramToWord, "bela");

private void lookupWord(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> anagramToWord, String wordToFind) {
    ArrayList<String> words = anagramToWord.get(lexicallySortWord(wordToFind));
    if (words != null) {
        System.out.println(wordToFind + " found as " + words
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    } else {
        System.out.println(wordToFind + " not present");
    }
}

private void populateAnagramLookup(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> anagramToWord) {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Addison\\wordlist.10000.txt");

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path.toFile());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String word;
        while ((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String sortedCharacters = lexicallySortWord(word);
            ArrayList<String> foundWords = anagramToWord.computeIfAbsent(sortedCharacters, k -> new ArrayList<String>());
            foundWords.add(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String lexicallySortWord(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: I had not considered this approach, thank you.  This looks like a lot cleaner approach than what I was taking.